# Ajax call from Plugin using Class

Tags: ajax, javascript

I'm making a plugin with a class and methods.

This class gets called through the theme ( hard coded ) to enqueue and localize my js. it also prepares it for ajax. However, i keep getting ERROR: 400

> POST `http://www.devsite.local/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` 400 (Bad Request)

I've ran ajax outside of a class in multiple plugins and at the functions.php with no issues, but i can't get it to work inside a class.

This is my code:

```
class CCYTFeatured {
public function __construct(){
        $this->cc_yt_scripts();
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'cc_yt_scripts' ));

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_cc_yt_featured', array( $this, 'cc_yt_featured' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cc_yt_featured', array( $this, 'cc_yt_featured' ) );

}
// Load CSS AND JAVA FRONT END
public function cc_yt_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'cc_yt_style',
        plugins_url( '/css/cc_yt.css', __FILE__ ),
        array(),
        cc_yt_version()
        );
    wp_enqueue_style('cc_yt_style');

    // JAVASCRIPT
    wp_register_script( 'cc_yt_javascript',
        plugins_url( '/js/cc_yt.js', __FILE__ ),
        array('jquery'),
        cc_yt_version(),
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script('cc_yt_javascript');
    wp_localize_script(
        'cc_yt_javascript',
        'cc_yt_script',
        array(
            'ajaxurl'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' , __FILE__ ),
            'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('my_nonce'),
        )
    );
}
public function cc_yt_featured(){

    check_ajax_referer( 'my_nonce', 'security' );
    echo json_encode('IM HERE, YOU CAN FIND US');
}
}
```

This is my JavaScript ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: cc_yt_script.ajaxurl,
    type : 'POST',
    data: {
        action : 'cc_yt_featured',
        security: cc_yt_script.ajax_nonce,
        post: 'bananas',
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('THIS IS THE RESPONSE:  '+ response);
    }
});
```

I keep getting the same error, i can't figure out what is wrong with my class:

This is how i call it.

```
$cc_yt = new CCYTFeatured;
```

I have that call hard coded inside a theme file. This does enqueue the styles and scripts successfully.

The ajax get is the following:

> `http://www.devsite.local/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=cc_yt_featured&security=79e39910b8&post=bananas`

Anyone have any clue what i'm doing wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: Note that  i tested it out side the classs ( copied the enquee and localizing out of the class and ran it) It work perfectly..
I think i might have an error on the way i have my class structured. I still need to be able to run the ajax call successfully from the class.

Comment: What happens if you place `$cc_yt = new CCYTFeatured;` in your functions.php file?

Comment: Have you considered using the more modern REST API instead? It's easier to debug, WP Admin AJAX isn't so forgiving with mistakes

Comment: Additionally, when you say "I have that call hard coded inside a theme file." which theme file are you referring to?

Comment: If `$cc_yt = new CCYTFeatured;` is inside a template, then it's not going to be run during an AJAX request, which means your callbacks won't be hooked, leading to a 400 error.

Comment: But, then why m i able to enqueue the styles and script??

$cc_yt is inside >woocommerce > single-product > product-image.php

Comment: Well you're not. Those scripts aren't going to load for the AJAX request either. Do you understand how AJAX works? AJAX requests are loading another PHP page in the background, but that's not going to include your template, so your code is not going to run for that request.

Comment: @JacobPeattie , ok. I'm no longer using __construct. Rather made a separate method.  Called the class and method inside the same plugin file and it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All the code is correct except the way i was calling.

I created a different method for __construct and then called it on the plugin it self so the scripts and styles get hooked before the templates. In my template i called the class again and the methods i need it. I no longer constructed my method all at once.